# Count preceding elements ignore a node

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<nd>
            <fn>
                <fnn>*</fnn>
                <fnt>
                    <p>
                        <i>ftn 1</i>
                    </p>
                </fnt>
            </fn>
            <ti>
                <fn>
                    <fnn>*</fnn>
                    <fnt>
                        <p>
                            <i>ftn 1</i>
                        </p>
                    </fnt>
                </fn>
            </ti>
            <tx>
                <fn>
                    <fnn>1</fnn>
                    <fnt>
                        <p>
                            <i>ftn2</i>
                        </p>
                    </fnt>
                </fn>
                <fn>
                    <fnn>2</fnn>
                    <fnt>
                        <p>
                            <i>ftn3</i>
                        </p>
                    </fnt>
                </fn>
            </tx>
        </nd>
```

Here i want to count the preceding `fnn` and create footnotes, but here i want to ingore the `preceding::tx`. I'm using the below XSLT.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:if test="//fnn">
                    <section class="tr_footnotes">
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<hr />]]></xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//page|//fnt" mode="footnote"/>
                    </section>
                </xsl:if>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fnn">
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(preceding::fnn)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="varHeaderNote" select='concat("f",$count)'/>
        <xsl:variable name="varFootNote" select='concat("#ftn.",$count)'/>
        <sup>
            <a name="{$varHeaderNote}" href="{$varFootNote}" class="tr_ftn">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </a>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="ti"/>

    <xsl:template match="fnt" mode="footnote">
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(preceding::fnn)"/>
        <div class="tr_footnote">
            <div class="footnote">
                <sup>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:text>ftn.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:text>#f</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                    </a>
                </sup>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

Here i'm able to ignore `ti` using `<xsl:template match="ti"/>`, but in thet count it is considering the `fnn` inside `ti`, here i want to ignore it and count. And in the footnotes section i'm unable to ignore it.

Here in thet head section.

After `ftn.0` it is generating `ftn.2`, but i want this to be `ftn 1`

And in the footnotes section there is `ftn.1` and `ftn.2`(This is the footnote from `ti`) and this should be ignored.

please let me know how can i fix this.

Here is the [working Demo](http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKww)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can change the counter by:

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="count(preceding::fnn[not(ancestor::ti)])"/>
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand completly the objectif, but try this method: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKww/8. It certainly has there an easier way, but it does not require to change whole code. It is necessary to change the counter and derive to template for the mode footnote, with an predicate to the fnt.